# Keep selected option in table selected

Tags: php, html, html-table

my problem is that i have a page where you can add rows to a table and in the table is a drop down.

For the dropdown it should automatically keep the selected index and the next added row should be the same option selected as the row above.
That works however the row above does not keep the selected option and resets to the first option.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../connect/db.php';
include '../../functions/function.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['row'])){
    $_SESSION['row'] = 1;
}

$def = 4;
$pass = 5;
$run = 3;

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $_SESSION['row']++;
}
if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
    $_SESSION['row']=1;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert Plays</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>


<div class="navbar">
    <a  href='home.php'>My Teams</a>
    <a   class="active" href=''>Insert Plays</a>
    <a   href='home.php?show=manage'>Manage Teams</a>
    <a href='edit_profile.php'>Edit Profile</a>
    <a class='log' href='../../index.php'>Logout</a>
</div>

<div class="content">


    <form action="" method="post">
    <table border="1">
    <?php
    $row = $_SESSION['row'];
    echo $row;
    $output = "";
        for($i = 0;$i<$row;$i++){
            $output .= "<tr>";
            if ($i == $_SESSION['row']-1){
                echo "Testaaaa";
                $test = "playType".($i-1);

                switch($_POST[$test]){
                    case 'pass':
                        $output .= "<td><select name='playType".$i."'>
                        <option selected value='pass' name='type'>Pass</option>
                        <option value='run' name='type'>Run</option>
                        <option value='def' name='type'>Def</option>
                        </select></td>";
                        break;
                    case 'run':
                        $output .= "<td><select name='playType".$i."'>
                        <option value='pass' name='type'>Pass</option>
                        <option selected value='run' name='type'>Run</option>
                        <option value='def' name='type'>Def</option>
                        </select></td>";
                        break;
                    case 'def':
                        $output .= "<td><select name='playType".$i."'>
                        <option value='pass' name='type'>Pass</option>
                        <option value='run' name='type'>Run</option>
                        <option selected value='def' name='type'>Def</option>
                        </select></td>";
                        break;

                };


            }
            else{
                $output .= "<td><select name='playType".$i."'>
                        <option value='pass' name='type'>Pass</option>
                        <option value='run' name='type'>Run</option>
                        <option value='def' name='type'>Def</option>
                        </select></td>";
            }
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }
        echo "$output";
    ?>
    </table>


        <input type="submit" value="Add Row" name="add"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">


    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using an old school form you would want to use another switch and put `selected` in different spots in your HTML String. I don't recommend using an old school form. Use the XMLHttpRequest with FormData instead.

Comment: I know it's old school. I'll try the XML

Comment: By XML, I'm assuming you really mean the XMLHttpRequest constructor. Good idea!